# Tasker Action does not trigger when SMS text string is in its received message

Tags: events, sms, tasker

I purchased the Tasker app to trigger repeated beeps after receiving a text message with 'CF203' text in its message. I can get these messages from different phones and it's hard to look at it in the night. my setup is as follows :

Note :
If I do not add any text string into 'Content'; simply Any, Action works fine. But when I add the text string, it does not respond.Also noticed it works fine when I text my self. but not from others.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the messaging app using RCS?
Try to put *CF201* in MMS body when you set up the event.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).